# Site-by-site rep gains for "today" are missing from achievements

Tags: support, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Take a look at this:

[image: screen shot]

Until now I've gotten the per-site total (like in yesterday's heading) even if I only gained rep on one site.  What happened here?

(If I gain rep on another site today and that changes the behavior here, I'll update.)

**Update** (2014-12-27): tonight I was greeted with this, but yesterday for a while I saw the behavior previously described (rep change on one site, site not called out):

[image: screen shot: rep change on one site and the site is shown at the top]

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have any screenshots from before that? I don't have the code in front of me, but I'm 99% sure we never showed a single-site rep gain like that.

Comment: @Anna (I finally got it) Single-site rep gain is displayed like that for already a year at least.

Comment: @AnnaLear I remembered I saw that before. Just for confirmation, is it only for yesterday's and today's reps, given there are rep changes in multi-sites? Because I don't see it for "last N days".

Comment: Can anyone show me a screenshot of what it's supposed to be? I can check tomorrow to see if anything changed, but AFAIK nobody's been working on the achievements UI, so either y'all are crazy or I am.

Comment: @Anna http://i.stack.imgur.com/6pfNO.png

Comment: @nicael That's the same as what Monica's showing here. Pretty sure that's how it's always been?

Comment: @Anna yep, sure

Comment: "What happened here?" - what should have happened?

Comment: Now that i think about it, you're right, it did used to show the site total even if it was only one site. It's been like this for a little while already.

Comment: @AnnaLear I know I've seen single-site display like in niceal's answer below.  Maybe it's been longer than I thought (I usually earn rep on more than one site each day).  Or maybe it was because of downvoting; not sure.  So you're saying that what's in my screenshot is what I'm supposed to see?  If so that's fine; I'm not asking for a change.  I just thought it wasn't what I was supposed to be seeing, is all.

Comment: I am nicael, not niceal :) Actually it *could* display rep site by site always earlier, you are the old user and you can remember it... But for the last year, its exactly the behavior I described.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm ... not sure. :) I didn't think we ever showed that, but nicael's screenshot shows that we did. I'll have to look at the code to check what's actually happening there.

Comment: @Anna Have you figured it out?

Comment: @nicael it's only 3 weeks, it needs 6-8 weeks to perform any operation. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear please see the update with a new screen shot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "exception" doesn't appear to be the case anymore - the rep gains are only shown separated if you have gained/lost the rep only on two or more sites, and if the said downvote is removed / the votes are undone, you're back to the situation shown on your first screenshot.

---

I remember that if you earned rep only on one site today or yesterday, it used to show rep for this day in the way shown on your pic (also in [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244684/site-by-site-rep-gains-for-today-are-missing-from-achievements#comment799875_244684)).

Exception would be if you had rep changes on multiple sites, e.g.: on MSE you had some upvotes, on SO casted a downvote on answer **and then** your downvote on SO is removed, you'll see your rep on this day "site-by-site", like this (I downvoted and undownvoted an answer):

> [image]